# How to change keyboard's DONE button,iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have 2 textfields, for login id and password.
When user taps on email id, they keyboard type is email and for password, its default.
They done button of both the keyboards, dismisses the keyboard.
WHat i am trying to do is, once user fills both the id and password, they DONE button should be changed to "LOGIN" and i can perform selector method on it to login.

Can this be doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using standard iOS keyboard, then the only available return key type is

```
typedef enum {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,         // “Return”
    UIReturnKeyGo,              // “Go”
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,          // “Google”.
    UIReturnKeyJoin,            // “Join”.
    UIReturnKeyNext,            // “Next”.
    UIReturnKeyRoute,           // “Route”.
    UIReturnKeySearch,          // “Search”.
    UIReturnKeySend,            // “Send”.
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,           // “Yahoo”.
    UIReturnKeyDone,            // “Done”
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,   // "Emergency Call”.
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

To detect the keychange on the keyboards you can register for name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification . Lets say your textfield are emailTextField and passwordTextField.

First you register the notification, the detect the text input

```
// emailTextField
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(check)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:emailTextField];

// passwordTextField
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(check)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:passwordTextField];

- (void)check {
  if ([emailTextField.text length] > 0 && [passwordTextField.text length] > 0) {
     // Set the return key here, e.g:
     emailTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
     passwordTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
  }
  else {
     // Set the return key here, e.g: 
     emailTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
     passwordTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
  }
}
```

When the return key tapped, it'll call textfield delegate. You can do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // You can perform selector here, probably after checking if both of the textfields already filled   out. E.g:
    if ([emailTextField.text length] > 0 && [passwordTextField.text length] > 0) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(login)];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: that worked.But how can i change the name of return button to login?

Comment: the only available keyboard return buttons are the ones I listed on the answer. If you want to use custom text, you need to go with the workaround @rishi posted as comment on your question -- http://mhasantanim.wordpress.com/tutorial/iphone/customize-done-button/

Comment: This works for me, but the button only updates when you move away from the field and come back. I tried resigningFirstResponder and then becomeFirstResponder again, but this doesnt work for password fields. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards, I'm not so sure, never need to do that before. But maybe this SO answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20510460/1473984.

Comment: @ewiinnnnn turns out you can just set enablesReturnKeyAutomatically to true, which suits my needs :)

Comment: @ChrisEdwards, thats great then

Answer (score 3):

`UITextInputTraits` protocol defines following `UIReturnKeyType` -

```
typedef enum {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

For your specific purpose you need to have custom button, you can check following tutorial - http://mhasantanim.wordpress.com/tutorial/iphone/customize-done-button/

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you use InterfaceBuilder, you can select your UITextField and in Attributes Inspector change the value of "Return Key" drop-down box.