# Changing uitextfield return key type while editing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have 4 uitextfields that recognize when they are empty or complete. If complete they change their return key type to GO, else is the default one. The problem is the keyboard is not changing the key type even though i use the reloadinputview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _fieldsArray = @[_nameField, _passwordField, _emailField, _usernameField];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSRange textFieldRange = NSMakeRange(0, [textField.text length]);

    //NSLog(@"%d", !(NSEqualRanges(range, textFieldRange) && [string length] == 0));

    [self signUpFieldsAreValid:(!(NSEqualRanges(range, textFieldRange) && [string length] == 0) && [self validateSignUpFields:textField])];
    [textField reloadInputViews];
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField{

    [self signUpFieldsAreValid:NO];
    [textField reloadInputViews];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    for (UITextField *aTextField in _fieldsArray) {
        if (aTextField.isFirstResponder) {

            aTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.f;
            aTextField.layer.borderColor = nil;

        }
    }

    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
    textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.f/255.f green:0.f/255.f blue:4.f/255.f alpha:1.f].CGColor;

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSUInteger fieldIndex = [_fieldsArray indexOfObject:textField];

    [_fieldsArray[(fieldIndex + 1) % 4] becomeFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateSignUpFields:(UITextField *)firstResponder
{
    for (UITextField *aTextField in _fieldsArray) {
        if (!aTextField.text.length && ![aTextField isEqual:firstResponder]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)signUpFieldsAreValid:(BOOL)valid
{
    NSLog(@"%d", valid);
    for (UITextField *aTextField in _fieldsArray) {

        if (valid) {
            aTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
        }
        else {
            aTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I used the following after changing the returnKeyType and it seemed to work very well in iOS7 and iOS6.1:

```
if ([self.textfieldOne isFirstResponder]) {
    [self.textfieldOne reloadInputViews];

}
```

Comment: Flipping brilliant.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Not to bring this up again after so long but i tried reloading the input views. Im working with Xcode 7.1 and ios9 right now, but its not working for me. Any ideas on how to do this now?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
{
    NSString *newStr=[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if([newStr length] > 0)
    {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
    }
    else
    {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    }
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, the `reloadInputViews` only affects custom input views, not the standard keyboard.

What I've done to solve this problem is to call `resignFirstResponder` then `becomeFirstResponder`. This will update the keyboard without any animation:

Instead of:

```
[textFiled reloadInputViews];
```

do:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Tried it right now but it didn't appear to have that effect. Is it possible that because I'm using ios 7 have any sort of consequences on it?

Comment: Do not work on ios6 & 7. And there will be some side effects, cause it will call `textFieldDidEndEditing:` then `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` methods.

Comment: [textField resignFirstResponder];
[textField becomeFirstResponder]; Works well!

Comment: As described by others comments here this is not safe especially if you have login in textFieldDidEndEditing and textFieldDidBeginEditing

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5

```
 // Change returnKeyType based on textField text
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // Change return key to Done when text entered
    if textField.text != "" {
        textField.returnKeyType = .done
        textField.reloadInputViews()
    }
    // Change back to default style if all text removed
    else {
        textField.returnKeyType = .default
        textField.reloadInputViews()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following after changing the returnKeyType and it seemed to work very well in iOS7 and iOS6.1:

```
if ([self.textfieldOne isFirstResponder]) {
    [self.textfieldOne reloadInputViews];

}
```